# can initializer_list container be changed?

Tags: visual-c++, initializer-list, stdmap

It seems that container elements are non-changeable after initialization. In the sample code, I want to change A's ch to 'c', but I get an error:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct A 
{
  A( char ch ) {}
};

struct H
{
  H( std::initializer_list< std::pair< const int, A > > initializerList ) : myMap( initializerList ) {}

  std::map< const int, A > myMap;
};

int main()
{
  H h { { 33, 'a' }, { 44, 'b' } };

  //h.myMap[ 33 ] = 'c'; // error C2512: 'A::A': no appropriate default constructor available

  return 0;
}
```

The rest of the error text is this:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(1203): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const int,A>::pair<std::tuple<_Ty &&>,std::tuple<>,0,>(_Tuple1 &,_Tuple2 &,std::integer_sequence<size_t,0>,std::integer_sequence<size_t>)' being compiled
with
[
  _Ty=const int,
  _Tuple1=std::tuple<const int &&>,
  _Tuple2=std::tuple<>
]
```

My questions are: 1) can an initializer list's container data, in this case an std::map, be made changeable? and 2) why is the compiler asking for a default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection of the initializer_list's _Elem types, I see there is a non-const interator. I have altered the original code which now works:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct A 
{
  A( char ch ) : ch( ch ) {}
  char ch;
};

struct H
{
  H( std::initializer_list< std::pair< const int, A* > > initializerList ) : myMap( initializerList ) {}

  std::map< const int, A* > myMap;
};

int main()
{
  H h { { 33, new A('a') }, { 44, new A( 'b' ) } };

  h.myMap[ 33 ] = new A( 'c' ); // ok

  return 0;
}
```

The smart pointer version of this code is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct A 
{
  A( char ch ) : ch( ch ) {}
  char ch;
};

struct H
{
  H( std::initializer_list< std::pair< const int, std::shared_ptr< A > > > initializerList ) : myMap( initializerList ) {}

  std::map< const int, std::shared_ptr< A > > myMap;
};

int main()
{
  H h { { 33, std::make_shared< A >('a') }, { 44, std::make_shared< A >( 'b' ) } };

  h.myMap[ 33 ] = std::make_shared< A >( 'c' ); // ok

  return 0;
}
```